# MVC 4 random value added to URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-4, random

For some reason on all of my URLs for my MVC 4 application the app seems to be adding random anchor values such as `#.Uhz_BdLbNz4` to the end of my URL and I cannot figure out why. I am sure its something simple but it is driving me nuts and I can't find anything about it online.

Does anyone know what it is and how to get rid of it?

Cheers

Danny

**Update:**
As requested my route config is just the standard one below

```cs
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

an example link:

```cs
    <a href="@Url.Action("Sessions", "Training", new { Month=DateTime.Now})">Find a Session >></a>
```

and finally some example generated HTML:

```html
    <ul class="top-nav cg-22-white">
        <li class="first-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mercedes/about">About Mercedes</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and

```html
<a href="/Training/Sessions?Month=08%2F27%2F2013%2020%3A44%3A44">Find a Session >></a>
```

Comment: Can we see your `RouteConfig` and maybe an example `@Html.ActionLink`/`@Html.RouteLink` (along with generated HTML from such)?

Comment: Ive updated the post with the items you have requested.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="/Training/Sessions?Month=08%2F27%2F2013%2020%3A44%3A44">Find a Session >></a>
```

The value at the end of the generated url is not random, it's a string representation of DateTime.Now-object you inserted in the annonymous object in the Url.Action-Helper.
If you don't what that parameter sent, just remove the annonymous object for the Url.Action

PS:
If you have a DateTime parameter on the action called month, this should be binded automatically for you.

Comment: Hi user9834. I know what the date parameter is but the app is appending something else on the URL and example is in my question but i have added it in this comment as well. It adds a strange # value.     **http://localhost:2989/news#.Uh0jGNLbNz4**

Comment: Is this strange # value only added to your url in the browser, or is it added to the html source? if it's added to the source, it would be helpful to see the generated code from the code in your question

Comment: It is only in the browser. It appears in Chrome, Firefox and IE so it has to be something the application is generating. What is shown in the source I have pasted above exactly as it was.